# HSQLDBs 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'-feature does not behave as in MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hsqldb

I am using MYSQLs `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`-feature, and it works as I expect when running on a MYSQL database. But when I try to write tests running against a in-memory HSQLDB, I experience different behaviour.

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, counter INT);
```

With the following insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO foo(id, counter) VALUES (1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1
```

- After the first run, counter is 1.
- After the second run, counter is 2.
- After the third run, counter is still 2. Here I expected the counter to be 3. (It is 3 if I run the same queries against MYSQL).

Is this a bug, or have I misunderstood how `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should work?

For a running example, see the following github-repository: https://github.com/mortenberg80/hsqldbtest

Comment: And what if `INSERT INTO foo(id, counter) VALUES (1, 11) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1` - counter stays `2` or become `12`?

Comment: [HSQLDB - Insert](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#insert-section) - no `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` support described.

Comment: `INSERT INTO foo(id, counter) VALUES (1, 11) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1`, then counter becomes 12.

Comment: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/compatibility-chapt.html#coc_compatibility_mysql describes `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`-support. (Added in later versions of HSQLDB)

Comment: Your query is executed as 2 separate statements it seems. First inserts a record (unconditionally? or new record replaces old one?), second increments inserted `counter` value.

Comment: Yeah, and this is not how it works in MYSQL :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial HSQLDB implementation of ON DUPLICATE UPDATE used the VALUES list as the source of the update in all cases where `col_name` was encounterd. It has been enhanced for version 2.5.1 to use the existing table row values as the source for `col_name`, and use the VALUES list as the source for VALUES(`col_name`). This corresponds with MySQL usage.